# How does using a Proxy in js making a Promise look synchronous actually work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

```
    const handler: ProxyHandler<any> = {
      get: (target: Promise<any>, prop: string, receiver: any) => {
        return target.then((o) => {
          return o[prop].apply(o);
        });
      },
    };
    return new Proxy(obj, handler);
```

So I have this code that I copied from a gist on the internet, and it seems to work. I understand how the trap works, but I don't get how the proxy makes a return of a promise act like a synchronous value. My colleague is afraid this code has a race condition. Are there any race conditions? what's actually happening under the hood? do I need to improve this code any to make it safe?

code is written in typescript and running on nodejs 10.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like this code makes access synchronous at all. It looks like it serves to make any *methods* on the promise payload available on the promise, but they will still have deferred execution when invoked.

For example, given the following API:

```
interface Bird {
  speak(): void;
}
function getBird(): Promise<Bird> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve({ speak() { console.log('CAW'); } }, 1000);
  });
}

function proxyPromise<T>(promise: Promise<T>) {
  // Your promise proxying code here
}
```

The proxyPromise code would allow you to call methods on the proxied object, and defer them until the promise is resolved:

```
const proxiedBird = proxyPromise(getBird());
console.log("Fetching Bird")
proxiedBird.speak;
console.log("Told it to speak");
```

This code would execute fine, but it won't make the `speak()` operation run synchronously--it will still wait for the `getBird()` promise to resolve. So in output you would see:

```
Fetching Bird
Told it to Speak
CAW
```

The code snippet you have would do nothing to support fields or methods with parameters on the proxied object.

You could describe its safe behavior with some typescript typing:

```
type MethodProxy<T> = {
  [idx in keyof T]: T[idx] extends () => infer U ? Promise<U> : never;
}

function proxyPromise<T>(promise: Promise<T>): MethodProxy<T> {
  const handler: ProxyHandler<any> = {
    get: (target: Promise<any>, prop: string, receiver: any) => {
      return target.then((o) => {
        return o[prop].apply(o);
      });
    },
  };
  return new Proxy(promise, handler);
}
```

Comment: but how does the proxy no to wait, vs returning a promise itself? as it looks like it is returning the promise. is this documented somewhere?

Comment: The `target.then()` line is operating on the promise, which is how it "knows to wait".

Answer (score 0):

Tricky question @xenoterracide. But answering you, actually, this doesn't work synchronously at all, basically, you turned every `obj` property to be accessed only asynchronously, and if the property is not a function, it throws an error.

Under the hood, you are only trapping a promise `get` properties, and in the trap, waiting for the promise to resolve and execute the property (function) in this value resolved by the promise.

I simulate it in [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAFgQzAEwDYFMBOAuGAFTEADwE8AJJNLAHiRID4YBeGAbwFgAoGHmAc3RRcACigJMAofkIBbAJYR0tMAwA0MAA6ENuaJjlg%206zOmDo5ANyy46ASmaMO3XiagBXTGBhiJggHRQcOhgwsIg9kyOXLwxMK4eXiAA2logGgC6fggaGqgkYbYA3NG8AL5FJTylqlylxZxcoJCwIABGAFbMbJUwCML2TrEuggkwAORkcmM91T2tuACstVyN4NCahKRdYOgA7tLE%20QQg8op%20JhAgqFZhHbbqiCgYmBUNnE2XGH6oIHzCqaQsrZVpAruhvr9-psSH5WsDOEA) playground:

```js
const handler: ProxyHandler<any> = {
    get: (target: Promise<any>, prop: string, receiver: any) => {
    return target.then((o) => {
        return o[prop].apply(o);
    });
    },
};

const obj = {
    a() {
        return 'Hi'
    },
    b: 5
}

const proxy = new Proxy(Promise.resolve(obj), handler);

//both prints promises
console.log(proxy.a) // after resolved, return 'Hi'
console.log(proxy.b) // error
```

This proxy approach could be useful if you don't want to resolve the promise itself. But you would need to `await` every property, and take care of not function ones.

Comment: but how does the proxy no to wait, vs returning a promise itself? as it looks like it is returning the promise. is this documented somewhere?

Comment: also I notice that you have `new Proxy(Promise.resolve(obj), handler)` is the resolve required to be safe? or wait?

Comment: The proxy didn't wait, all of its `get` trap will return a `Promise`. And **you** will have to wait to get that property. 
Second comment, the `Promise.resolve()` is just a way to return a `Promise` that always resolves straightforward. In this case, I did it just to avoid calling the constructor